# Strange java LatLng condition

Tags: java

Is the following original code (scroll to right)

```
boolean b = this.southwest.longitude <= this.northeast.longitude ? this.southwest.longitude <= var1 && var1 <= this.northeast.longitude :
                                                           this.southwest.longitude <= var1 || var1 <= this.northeast.longitude;
```

same as this? (my interpretation)

```
if (this.northeast.longitude)
{
  boolean b = this.southwest.longitude <= var1 && var1 <= this.northeast.longitude;
} else {
  boolean b = this.southwest.longitude <= var1 || var1 <= this.northeast.longitude;
}
```

because it feels it is more like this weird condition (mix of comparing boolean and longitude)

```
if (this.southwest.longitude)
{
    boolean b = this.southwest.longitude <= (this.southwest.longitude <= var1 && var1 <= this.northeast.longitude);

} else {
    boolean b = this.southwest.longitude <= (this.southwest.longitude <= var1 || var1 <= this.northeast.longitude);

}
```

What i am trying to do, is to manually build conditions of LatLngBounds.contains() to perform query on NOSQL db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither, nor. It is:

```
boolean result;
if(this.southwest.longitude <= this.northeast.longitude){   
    result = this.southwest.longitude <= var1 && var1 <= this.northeast.longitude;
} else {
    result = this.southwest.longitude <= var1 || var1 <= this.northeast.longitude;
}
```

`a ? b : c` is just "syntactic sugar" for `if a then b else c`

Comment: Ahh.. I see. thank you very much. I was thinking it looked bit weird to me.

Comment: I know, you see i built condition of it, but i intepreted wrong the parts of the ternary operator. You have it correctly, but i thought it begins at "this.northeast.longitude" but it began at "this.southwest.longitude <= this.northeast.longitude"

Comment: If I were you, I'd rather not use ?: here. Makes it really unreadable.

Comment: Yea thats not my code, thats decompiled code of LatLngBounds.contains(), but i need to build the conditions upon it and run it on NOSQL.

Comment: OK, I see. That's also of course really opinionated of me. See, I had some fellow coders a while ago, that made really excessive use of that operator for each and every if's. And they even constructed really complicated structures like `a ? b ? c: d? f : e : g` ... up to the point where it seemed they wanted to purposely obfuscate the code. It was a debugging nightmare. Therefore my dislike for it. I use it only when it is really clear and readable.

Comment: Yes but question isnt about that i suggest to use complicated ternary operators but about how to interpret this specific case, but thx anyways.